# How to delete/remove the recent devices in shareit APP?

Tags: shareit

We can delete the history of the devices but we cannot remove the recent devices from Shareit. But in Bluetooth and we can unpair the paired devices and that won't be visible until we again pair the devices.

Comment: You can set password for connecting devices.

Answer (score -1):

As of now, there is no way possible to do that. But you can go to the link [SHAREit|Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en) and can add a comment in review section and for this functionality in next version.

Meanwhile goto **App info** and **clear data** for SHAREit to remove recent devices. **But it will remove every data related to SHAREit** ie it will also remove your user and you have to again create a user to use Shareit.